# What is the unit "Th" as in Th/s?

Tags: hashpower, terminology

I keep seeing this everywhere, but it seems impossible to search. What does Th stand for? What does it mean? How do you calculate the Th?

For example, "The 13.5 TH/s is $2773.28 US". What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

oops, I should make it an answer, not a comment:

Tera Hashes - a kind of a speed indicator, how fast the mining machine can calculate. "The 13.5 TH/s is $2773.28 US" would mean, a machine with such a power can generate this amount of Dollars...

Comment: I believe the $2773.28 is referring to the cost of such a miner, not how much it earns?

Comment: yup, might as well be this, I haven't had the prices for the miner boxes in mind.